# Calling a hook (useMutation) inside an event handler error: "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, mutation

I want to use a mutation in an event handler. My event is defined like so:

```
(JSX attribute) onOk?: ((e: React.MouseEvent<any, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined
```

This is how I call the mutation from the client

```
export const IMPORT_INFO_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation ImportPolicy($data: ImportPolicyInput!) {
    importPolicy(data:$data)
    {
      _id
      name
    }
 }
```

And eventually I call it like so:

```
      onOk={() => {

        useImportPolicyMutation({
          variables: {
            data: {
              jsonData: JSON.parse(importPolicyData)
            }
          },
        })
      }
```

`Don't worry about the variables and params in the mutation. They are fine. The issue is that I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only 
be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for 
one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

It is a hook because the useMutation is defined like so:

```
  return ReactApolloHooks.useMutation<ImportPolicyMutation, ImportPolicyMutationVariables>(
   ImportPolicyDocument,
baseOptions
 )
```

So, how do I call a mutation inside an event handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, how do I call a mutation inside an event handler?

1. **Hooks are ONLY for functional components**, not for class based (use apollo `client.mutation()` or `<Mutation/>` component)
2. `useMutation` returns function intended to be used on demand - this function must be used in event handler, not entire `useMutation`

react-apollo-hooks project description contains an example of [usemutation](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks#usemutation) used with event handler.

Comment: Ok, the thing is that from a UI standpoint it makes sense to create the useMutation at the same time I want to use it. When the user press the OK button. When looking at this it seems like I need to create a middle button like OK1 where useMutation creates a function and when pressing OK2 I can execute this function

Comment: Hooks are used unconditionally (requirement) - `useMutation` creates a function - you can use it or not - UI can use it or not - it's not UI role to decide when create function UI can use

Comment: Got it now, yes it was the class ReactApolloHooks.useMutation that made this problem. Thanks!